# Android - repo sync fails with fatal: Unable to look up android.git.kernel.org (port 9418) (Name or service not known)

Tags: android, git, repository

**repo sync** fails with the following message:

```
$ repo sync
fatal: Unable to look up android.git.kernel.org (port 9418) (Name or service not known)
fatal: Unable to look up android.git.kernel.org (port 9418) (Name or service not known)
error: Cannot fetch repo
```

It seems that [kernel.org has been hacked](http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/News/Kernelorg-hacked/), so this is what is causing the issue.
Is there a workaround to resolve this issue and not to completely switch to different Android repository (such as those on github, etc)?

Comment: i dont think so because it is down!

Comment: What is the problem with switching to different repository?

Answer (score 1):

All of the code is now in github at http://www.github.com/android. I don't believe Google has made the necessary changes to the manifest (or the repo tool itself, which has a hardcoded URL to kernel.org) to pull from there easily.  You could probably make it work with some hacking around.